How to create Microsoft.Azure.Devices.ServiceClient instance using ClientSecretCredential ie ClientId,TenantId,ClientSecret
How to create Microsoft.Azure.Devices.ServiceClient instance using ClientSecretCredential ie ClientId,TenantId,ClientSecret
Can we make AzureSasCredential or TokenCredential So that i can use Create methods ! Helps appreciated !
Or how do we get SharedAccessKey,SharedAccessKeyName if we know  ClientSecretCredential
ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connString) this works with SharedAccessKey etc but this is not intended!
I can get access token but this cannot be used for
var clientCred = new ClientSecretCredential(message.TenantId, message.ClientId, message.ClientSecret);
var tocken2 = await clientCred.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new string[] { scope }))


please share the code you tried in the above question

The code below uses a Microsoft.Azure.Devices.ServiceClient instance with ClientSecretCredential, which employs the ClientId, TenantId, and ClientSecret.
Create a ServiceClient instance using the HostName and the ClientSecretCredential.

Used this link to Control access to IoT Hub by using Microsoft Entra ID
Code for ServiceClient taken from GitHub


            string hostName = "your-iot-hub.azure-devices.net";  // Your IoT Hub host name
            string deviceId = "your-device-id";  // Your target device ID
            string clientId = "your-client-id";  // Your Azure AD application client ID
            string tenantId = "your-tenant-id";  // Your Azure AD tenant ID
            string clientSecret = "your-client-secret";  // Your Azure AD application client secret
            
           instance using your client ID, tenant ID, and client secret
            ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
            
            // Create a ServiceClient instance using the hostname and the ClientSecretCredential instance
            // You can specify the transport type (e.g., Amqp or Amqp_WebSocket_Only)
            TransportType transportType = TransportType.Amqp;
            ServiceClient serviceClient = ServiceClient.Create(hostName, clientSecretCredential, transportType);
            
            // Use the ServiceClient instance to communicate with the IoT Hub
            // Example: Send a message to a device
            await serviceClient.OpenAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection opened to IoT Hub.");

            string messageText = "Hello, Cloud!";
            Message cloudToDeviceMessage = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageText));

            // Send the message to the device
            await serviceClient.SendAsync(deviceId, cloudToDeviceMessage);
            Console.WriteLine($"Message sent to device {deviceId}: {messageText}");

            
            await serviceClient.CloseAsync();


Output:



Refer to this SO to get SharedAccessKey for Azure IoT-Hub and refer to this example with SharedAccessKey.
Create a device in IoT Hub via REST API or SDK

